# Captain Ralph is in trouble near the sunny side of Mecury.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

The temperature of the ship's hull when he is at location $(x,y,z)$ will be given by $T(x,y,z)= e^{-x^2-2y^2-3z^2}$, where $x,y,$ and $z$ are measured in meters. He is currently at $(1,1,1)$.

**(A)** In what direction should he proceed in order to decrease the temperature most rapidly?

**(B)** If the ship travels at $e^8$ meters per second, how fast will be the temperature decrease if he proceeds in that direction?

**(C)** Unfortunately, the metal of the hull will crack if cooled at a rate greater than $\sqrt{14}e^2$ degrees per second. Describe the set of possible directions in which he may proceed to bring the temperature down at no more than that rate.

So I tried to the partial derivatives of each variable, but they all end up negative. However, I think for question **(A)**, the answer should be in the direction of the $z$ direction because it has the greatest negative coefficient in the equation. Is that correct?

For **(B)**, do I just plug in $e^8$ into the partial derivative of $z$?

For **(C)**, what do I do?

Comment: I don't have a complete answer, but for **(A)**, you should find the gradient at $(1,1,1)$, then multiply that by $-1$, because the gradient will get you the direction of the biggest temperature increase, and multiplying it will get you the opposite.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Do you have any idea for $B$ or $C$?

Comment: For **(C)**, you have to use the directional derivative, in which you take the dot product of the gradient with a *normalized* direction vector, and find where it is less than $\sqrt{14}e^2$.

Answer (score 0):

**(A)**

Taking the gradient of $T$ yields $\nabla T (x,y,z) = \langle -2 x e^{-x^2-2 y^2-3 z^2},-4 y e^{-x^2-2 y^2-3 z^2},-6 z e^{-x^2-2 y^2-3 z^2} \rangle$. This gives the direction of maximum increase of any point $(x,y,z)$.

Since we're at $(1,1,1)$ and want the maximum decrease, the appropriate vector is

> $$-\nabla T (1,1,1) = \langle \frac{2}{e^6},\frac{4}{e^6},\frac{6}{e^6} \rangle \approx \langle 0.0049575, 0.00991501, 0.0148725 \rangle$$

Since we're only after the *direction* of maximum decrease, we should normalize this result, giving:

> $$\vec{e}= \frac{ - \nabla T (1,1,1)}{\| - \nabla T (1,1,1) \|} = \left\langle -\frac{1}{\sqrt{14}},-\sqrt{\frac{2}{7}},-\frac{3}{\sqrt{14}} \right\rangle$$

Note that this is not simply heading in the $z$ direction, but off at an angle.

**(B)**

Recall that if $\vec{r}(t)$ is a parametrized path, then $\frac{d}{dt} T(\vec{r}(t)) = \nabla T(\vec{r}(t)) \cdot \vec{r}'(t)$---this is really just the chain rule in disguise. Since we want to head in the direction of maximum decrease, it is useful to know that $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = \| \vec{u} \| \|\vec{v} \| \cos \theta$. So in our case $\theta=0$ and

> the rate of *decrease* is $ \| \nabla T(1,1,1) \| \mathrm{e}^8= 2 \sqrt{14}e^2$ or the rate of change is $-2\sqrt{14}e^2$.

**(C)**

Since the ship's hull will crack if the rate of change is greater than $\sqrt{14}e^2$, we need to head off at an angle $\theta$ relative to the direction of maximum decrease. This means that we want

> $\big| \|\nabla T(1,1,1) \| \mathrm{e}^8 *\cos \theta \big| \leq \sqrt{14}e^2$

which means that

> $| 2 \sqrt{14}e^2 \cos \theta | \leq \sqrt{14}e^2$ which gives that $|\cos \theta| \leq \frac{1}{2} \implies \theta \in [\pi/3, 2 \pi 3]$

Comment: I thoroughly understand what you did on $C$, but how did you do $B$. I'm a little confused with the chain rule and what you did with the parametrized path.

Comment: We could actually give an appropriate parametrized path, with $\vec{r} (0) = \langle 1,1,1\rangle$ and $\| \vec{r}'(0) \| = e^8$, with $\vec{r}'(0)$ pointing in the direction of $-\nabla T (1,1,1)$. However, by using the formula for the dot product that I gave, we can bypass this difficulty. It's enough to know what the magnitude of $\vec{r}'$ is and what angle we're heading (relative to the gradient).

Comment: Note that the "Chain rule for paths" really just reduces to the directional derivative, but I can never remember the formula for the later.

Comment: I see how you got the answer now. However, my only problem is now how did you get the unit vector of the gradient. I used the formula of squaring and square rooting and somehow I can't get it to the way you got it.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose we're really after the *direction*, so we want a unit vector in the direction of $-\nabla T(1,1,1)$, which would be $\langle -\frac{1}{\sqrt{14}},-\sqrt{\frac{2}{7}},-\frac{3}{\sqrt{14}} \rangle$. Edited my answer to include.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a little lost. How did you go from $∥∇T(1,1,1)∥e^8=2\sqrt{14}e^2$?